# BEMCheckBox Designables Failed

Tags: ios, swift, ibdesignable, bridging-header

When I tried to bridge BEMCheckBox with Swift.
 I have got the below error
**NO target found containing the source files BEMCheckBox.Make Sure the one files are in the target**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RpxJ.png)

**I have tried the following steps as suggested by the forums**

1. ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData. Deleted the DerivedData folder
2. update the pod

But the none of these worked out.

please provide me input on this.

Answer (score 0):

I have copied  class folder into workspace. The classes in the class folder are not compiled properly.

so I have deleted the class folder.

I have created the Group named 'class' and copied all the files in the class group.

Make sure the class are present in Compile sources.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhYsx.png)